# Throw exception if calling thread is not the thread that created the object

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to create an instance of my custom class. For example, I have two threads `T1` and `T2`. If I create instance from `T1`, any access to that instance from `T2` should throw an exception. Like in WinForms, when I try access control from thread which is not UI thread.

How to achieve this? Should I store reference to `current thread` or should I keep some `unique ID` of the current thread? (if that ID exists). Which mechanism shoud I use?

Basically it will be a singleton that generates random numbers form given seed. I want to block access to this singleton from other threads, because I need to run my app again with same seed to reproduce my scenario. If I will alow to use this class from other threads, then reproduction will be not possible because threads start/stops/do actions in unpredictible order.

Comment: Why? Why not fix the code so that it's thread-safe? A simple `lock(){..}` in the method that returns the random number should be enough

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7610982/574632

Comment: You don't need a singleton if you only want to access the object from the main form or a single object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: if I have Random(seed) and then I do 10x call to random.Next() - I am able to reproduce this numbers when I start my app again. If I do random.Next() at two threads at same time - reproduction will be not possible.

Comment: @zgnilec then don't. If the numbers should be server from a single point, don't use a singleton. If the generator is a private field or method, the compiler itself will prevent other classes from accessing it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Generator cant be private. Seed is generated randomly - then I start test (im testing a product). If test will fail - it is required to reproduce test with same random numbers. So I set seed in configuration file and all numbers are generated like in previous test run. Test can have may iteraitons, so for each iteration sub-seed should be used. I can skip some iterations etc. So I need that singleton or other smarter class. I used signelton for now because there is no other option for now (need refactor).

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use [Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx) for that purpose.

Note, however, that these IDs might get re-used at some time, so they may not be unique accross the lifespan of your application. However, given the scenario you've described, I think that this should not be an issue.

Also you need to be aware that your 'guard' may not play well with async coding depending on how and where it is used.

Comment: If ManagedThreadId can be reused it is not good for me. However I will create my class on main thread, so it will work. But storing reference is good or not?

Comment: Well, any 32-bit ID may get re-used over time in a long-running application. Also, you have the thread pool which can re-use threads (which then hold the same ID of course). So it depends very much on the circumstances. At any given time, no two IDs can collide, so the re-use should not be an issue in your case as I wrote already, assuming that the "authorized" thread is alive no other thread will get is managed ID at the same time.

Comment: currently im storing in a private field reference to Thread.CurrentThread in my Initialize() method. And I some important methods, I have somethind like: lock (...) { if (Thread.CurrentThread != savedThreadReference) throw new InvalidOperationException ("Cross-thread..."); Is it good?